# if statements always execute

Tags: c++, visual-c++, if-statement

I'm having issues with my `if` statements running into each other. Here is my code:

```
std::cout << "1) Option 1\n";
std::cout << "2) Option 2\n";
std::cout << "3) Option 3\n";
std::cout << "4) Option 4\n";
std::cout << "Type your choice and hit ENTER \n";

std::cin >> Choice;

if(Choice == 1); 
{
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
}
if(Choice == 2);
{
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
}
if(Choice == 3);
{
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
}
if(Choice == 4);
{
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
}
```

By running into each other I mean: it will just ignore my `if` statements and run all of my code so it would just print out:

```
Blah Blah
Blah Blah
Blah Blah
Blah Blah
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: You have semicolons after your ifs.

Comment: And, you should read your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 30):

Your semicolons need to be removed, they are terminating the if statement.

```
if(Choice == 1)
{
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
}
if(Choice == 2)
{
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
}
if(Choice == 3)
{
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n"
}
if(Choice == 4)
{
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
}
```

You could use else ifs as well to clean up your code.

Comment: No problem. We've all made these seemingly simple mistakes at some point :)

Comment: @THUNDERGROOVE See if you can enable more warnings on your compiler. For example on my compiler your code gives me a bunch of "warning: if statement has empty body [-Wempty-body]", and points directly to the offending semicolons.

Answer (score 5):

Why didnt you use a switch statement here?  Will really clean your code up.

```
std::cin >> Choice;

switch(Choice)
{
case 1:
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
break;

case 2:
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
break;

case 3:
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
break;

case 4:
std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
break;
}
```

Comment: What if he forgets the `break` statements?

Comment: @Inverse then all hell `break`s loose

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the semicolon limiting the scope of your if statements , I would like to suggest you use a nested if loops . They are faster to execute.

Comment: If is not a loop. I don't see how they could be nested here, and even if they could they *certainly* would not be faster to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `;` in front of the `if` conditions and it will work. Also, because the options are mutually exclusive, better write it like this:

```
if (Choice == 1) {
    std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
} else if (Choice == 2) {
    std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
} else if (Choice == 3) {
    std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
} else if (Choice == 4) {
    std::cout << "Blah Blah\n";
}
```

... Or use a `switch`, as has been pointed out in other answers.