Loop counting code doesn't work correctly
I'm pretty new and just started programming around 3 days ago. I've finished learning the basics and am now stuck in this problem, but I can't seem to debug it.
I want it to go through the integer to find all 3s, but instead, it counts every number in it (for example, if I enter 1212, it answers back 4. I want a 0.)
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long n; 
    cin >> n; 
    int cnt = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        int k = n % 10; 
        if (k == 3); { 
            cnt++;
        }
        n /= 10;
    }
    cout << cnt;
}


All help would be appreciated. Thanks for reading!
EDIT: I just found out that this question was asked before. Stackoverflow won't let me delete this post, so I'll just put a reminder here. Thank you all!

What do you mean "can't seem to debug it"? Have you used the debugger? If not, try to do so

You have a stray semicolon after your if statement. It effectively ends the if block, so everything after it will run regardless, so counting all digits.

Oh, I noteced the semicolon now too. I'll explain what happens when you put a semicolon here in an answer

if (k == 3); {cnt++;} means if (k == 3){} cnt++;

There's an incorrect semi-colon here if (k == 3); {, just delete it.

@yurich an answer isn't really appropriate, it should either be closed as a typo or a duplicate of e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568666/if-statements-always-execute

thank you all for the help!

@AlanBirtles, I think it's important for a newbie to understand what statements are and why exactly it works

@Animoise learn to compile with all warnings enabled, and warnings as errors. That would have given you a compile error pointing to the semi colon.

If you are new you can still unlearn to use long long and using namespace std; . long long is usually not really needed and using namespace is not recommended.

i would HIGHLY advice you to use longer variable names. We are not in the 1950's were you need to chose every single byte of text you write. Use names that make it easy to understand what is going on.
@PepijnKramer both are fine for learning the language.

@ABaumstumpf For learning yes, but unlearning "habits" early on is also advisable :) And yes longer variable names help a lot. Good code should almost read like a recipe

This is because you are using a semi colon after the if statement
if (k == 3);

The correct way is (and after removing ; the code worked perfectly fine)
if (k == 3)

In C++, you do not add ; after if statement.

You have a semicolon after the condition in the if statement.
Brackets in C form compound statements or "blocks". When you write an if statement or a loop, you add brackets to form a compound statement, otherwise only the first statement will be executed.
If you place a semicolon directly after the condition it will think that you just ended the statement and the body is empty (equivalent to {};). The compount statement after the semicolon is now not related to the if statement - in C you can have them on their own (to limit variable scopes and stuff), that's why it works and works every time.

You have used a semicolon after the if statement which terminates it and the counter runs normally without considering the condition.
Remove the semicolon and the loop should work fine.
